# Alfresco openCMIS connect to home folder

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

In Alfresco I have this structure /Company Home/A and /Company Home/B some users home folders are set to A and others set to B.

Problem: I see that in order to connect from my application to Alfresco though OpenCMIS, I need connect there using the repositoryId, aka MainRepository(Company home), so I need give all users from A and B permissions to connect to there. So that´s means that if a users from A connect to Alfresco, they can read documents from B, and the other way around.

I was expecting using OpenCMIS can connect directly to my home folder.

Any idea or suggestion about my issue?.

Thanks

Comment: Why not set permissions on `/Company Home/A` so that only people from A can access it, `/Company Home/B` so that only B people can get it it, and global read to `/Company Home` ? An A user connecting to home would only see the A subfolder, B users the B one, and only admin both. Won't that do it?

Comment: @Gagravarr You just describe what I want, but I cannot achieve that!, if I give permissions on Company home/ Automatically you have permissions for read all  nested folders of Company home. Do you know Alfresco?, do you know how to achieve what you just describe?. Thanks

Comment: You can control if permissions are inherited or not. Turn off inheritance on the A and B subfolders, and you should be set!

Comment: you´re the man! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer:

What you need to do is:

1. Give all users Read (Consumer) access to `/Company Home`
2. Give only B users access to `/Company Home/B` and remove `Inherit Permissions` to stop A users having access
3. Give only A users access to `/Company Home/A` and remove `Inherit Permissions` to stop B users having access

To do those changes, use the *Repository Browser* to be able to play with Company Home, then use *Manage Permissions*. Clock on `Inherit Permissions` and go through a prompt to remove them, then add in the appropriate groups. It should look roughly like

[image: Before]

[image: After]